# Copy a file to the clipboard in HTML

Tags: html, clipboard

I've Googled around this for an hour and not found anything suitable, but it feels like something that surely should exist and be quite easy/common? So I'm asking here.

I'm planning on hosting a number of small files on my server. These contain Midi information (used in music production).

What I want is to create an HTML page that lists each of these midi files, and allows the user to click a button to copy the file straight to their clipboard, so that they don't have to download each file and then locate it in their downloads folder.

I can't find any solution for this. I've found lots of solutions for copying text, but I want to copy a file instead - Is this possible?

Primarily I'm open to using HTML, PHP or JavaScript.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. (You could perhaps encode the file as text and then copy that, but that doesn't seem helpful for your use case)

Comment: I agree with @DBS - I would be very, very surprised if you're able to do this

Comment: Hmmmm - ok thanks for your input anyway. WIll just have to accept that users must download the files